# ChartJS on a bootstrap carousel (or any slide show)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js, carousel

I am trying to build an automatic slide show where it will display some charts ( around 10 graphs ) in a dashboard page. In order the page be readable in a TV I think it should display one graph at time, otherwise the screen will look polluted with so many information. I would like to create this slide show in an interval 5s to go to next bar chart. I am open to work with another plugin if that will be the case. So far what I've done it is on this snippet.

Thanks.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
  await getOrders();
});

async function getOrders() {
  do {
    var charts = [];
    var width;
    var height;

    width = $('#carousel-example-generic').width();
    height = $('#carousel-example-generic').height();

    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: false,
    });
    let response, data;
    let clientId = page.user.id;
    try {
      response = await fetch(apiServer + "orders/stat");
      data = await response.json();

      if (!response.ok) {
        page.notification.show("Error: " + data.result);
        break;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      page.notification.show("Error: Could not connect to the server.");
      break;
    }
    await createContainers(data.total_by_store);
    await populateContainers(data.total_by_store);
  } while (0);
}

function createContainers(total_by_store){
  let barCharts = document.getElementById("barCharts");
  let ol = document.querySelector('.carousel-indicators');
  let firstOne = true;
  for (let i=0; i < total_by_store.length; i++){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.dataset.target = '#carousel-example-generic';
    li.dataset.slideTo = i;
    if (i == 0){
      li.classList.add('active');
    }
    ol.appendChild(li);
  }
  let carouselInner = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');
  for (let storeOrders of total_by_store){
      let div1 = document.createElement('div');
      if (firstOne == true){
        div1.classList.add('active');
        firstOne = false;
      }
      div1.classList.add('item');
      let div2 = document.createElement('canvas');
      div2.setAttribute('id', 'store-'+storeOrders.store);
      div2.setAttribute('class', 'chart');
      div2.style.width = "100%";
      div2.style.height = "360px";
      div1.appendChild(div2);
      carouselInner.appendChild(div1);
  }
}

function populateContainers(total_by_store){
  var charts = [];
  var width;
  var height;

  width = $('#carousel-example-generic').width();
  height = $('#carousel-example-generic').height();

  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false,
  });
  for (let storeOrders of total_by_store){
    let labels = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(storeOrders).slice(1);
    let labelsConverted = [];
    for (let label of labels){
      label = page.labelNames[label];
      labelsConverted.push(label);
    }
    let myChart = new Chart('store-'+storeOrders.store, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: labelsConverted,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: stores[storeOrders.store].name,
            data: Object.values(storeOrders).slice(1),
            backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(labelsConverted),
            borderColor:  getBorderColor(labelsConverted),
            borderWidth: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: stores[storeOrders.store].name
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              callback: function(value) {if (value % 1 === 0) {return value;} }
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.2,
          }]
        }
      }
    });
    myChart.render();
    charts.push(myChart);
  }
  $(window).resize(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
      charts[i].options.width = $('.carousel').width();
      charts[i].options.height = $('.carousel').height();
      charts[i].render();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  //margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-image: none !important;
  filter: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
     -moz-border-radius: 23px;
          border-radius: 23px;  
}

.glyphicon{
    font-size: 60px;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/orders.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/orders.js" type="module"></script> 
<body>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

UPDATE:

```
That what my html looks like after the javascript runs, everything looks fine but the carousel does not work and all charts are shown on the page.

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="/common/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/client/css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/orders.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/orders.js" type="module"></script> 
<body>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li><li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li><li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <div class="active item">
    <div class="chartjs-size-monitor">
      <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand">
        <div class=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink">
          <div class=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="store-1" style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 400px; display: block; width: 600px; height: 300px;" width="600" height="300" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
  </div>



  <div class="item"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"><div class=""></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"><div class=""></div></div></div><canvas id="store-4" style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 400px; display: block; width: 600px; height: 300px;" width="600" height="300" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"><div class=""></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"><div class=""></div></div></div><canvas id="store-7" style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 400px; display: block; width: 600px; height: 300px;" width="600" height="300" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas></div>


  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Got an example for you, its far off from what you have with your current setup, you will need to add your custom code to load the data but the caroucel with charts in it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/1f7mr6q0/7/

Comment: @LeeLenalee Thanks. I've loaded all data through JS but the carousel seems like is not working, although I didn't get any errors on the console.